# Getting results from List<IMongoQuery>

Tags: c#, mongodb

The code I'm working on at the moment uses the C# Mongo driver and I do lots of simple stuff like this

```
var query = Query.EQ("SomeBooleanField", false);
return Collection.FindAs<MyType>(query);
```

I have a requirement to write a query that is dynamic, i.e. the number of AND clauses varies. So I'm using something like this -

```
var andList = new List<IMongoQuery>();
if (whatever) 
    andList.Add(Query.EQ("Field1", true));

if (suchandsuch) 
    andList.Add(Query.EQ("Field2", false));

var query = new QueryBuilder<MyType>();
query.And(andList);
```

So my question is, what do I do with **query** in order to get some results out of it? I want a List or IEnumerable.

I can't find any useful examples online and the driver documentation isn't too helpful. Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: can you post your whole code. can't you put 'query' in a collection.Find(query).ToListAsync(); ??

Comment: Hi, can't post code because of client's IP concerns. But, if I do this -


    var query = new QueryBuilder<MyType>();
    query.And(andList);
    return Collection.FindAs<MyType>(query);

I get an error - MongoDb.Driver.Builders.QueryBuilder<MyType> is not assignable to parameter type ' MongoDb.Driver.IMongoQuery'.

... (also the 'Collection' variable I'm using doesn't have a 'Find' method).

Comment: I have posted a sample code in an answer. please comment on that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following this format

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MyCollection");
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("param1", "value1") & builder.Eq("param2", "value2");
var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

you are getting an error because you cannot use the FindAS<>()is this case

Comment: In my original post, the 'Collection' variable I'm using doesn't have a 'Find' method.

When I try the code above it tells me that 'filter' is a FilterDefinition and I'm trying to pass it into Find() where Find() is expecting an IMongoQuery.